# Include layout and exclude another one

Tags: java, android, xml

In my project i have 3 xml files.

My main layout

and 2 layouts which i want to include in my main layout

*big_buttons.xml* >contains big size buttons
*small_buttons.xml* >contains the same buttons as above (same id's aswell) but they are smaller

By default i want the *big_buttons.xml* included, but id like to be able to "exclude" the *big_buttons.xml* and include the *small_buttons.xml* programmaticly after an onClickListener

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can use `setContentView(R.layout.big_buttons);`, and then in your onClickListener you could do `setContentView(R.layout.small_buttons);`

If it's specific buttons you want excluded rather than the entire XML, I think you need to combine the 2 XML files and by default give the "big buttons" the attribute `android:visibility="visible"` and the "small buttons" `android:visibility="gone"`.

Then programmatically you can do

```
    Button bigButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
    Button smallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.small_button);

    bigButton.setVisibility("View.GONE");
    smallButton.setVisibility("View.VISIBLE");
```

You'll want to use GONE rather than INVISIBLE because GONE excludes layout features like height and width, where INVISIBLE just doesn't display the button, but keeps space for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [View.setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).  You can use this on a layout manager, so that you can make entire groups of controls visible or invisible from Java code.